# Changing datatype of calculation in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, date, types, extract

I am extracting the year from a date and subtracting it from another year but for some reason I keep getting a float as a result. How can I fix this? Thanks a bunch

```
    SELECT 2022-(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CAST(birthdate AS DATE)))AS age
    FROM animals
```

Result:[image: Result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `EXTRACT` function return type was `double precision`, if you want to get value of integer you can try to convert the type to `INT` after using `EXTRACT`.

```
SELECT 2022-(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CAST(birthdate AS DATE)))::INT AS age
FROM animals
```